# I am exporting SQLite data file in Android but it only gets visible when I reboot the mobile

Tags: android, sqlite, export, reboot

Using Following soucre Code, I am exporting SQLite data file in Android. It successfully exports data file but it only gets visible when I reboot the mobile.

I am using **non rooted mobile** and I am only interested exported data in non rooted mobiles. So kindly do not provide solutions for rooted mobiles.

```
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

if(sd.canWrite())
{
String currentDBPath = "//data//"+ packageName +"//databases//"+"DB";
String backupDBPath = "DB";
File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

if (currentDB.exists()) {
FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
src.close();
dst.close();
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "not visible" you mean it's not visible when you mount the device via USB MTP.

Use [`MediaScannerConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html) to notify the system of your newly created file so it gets added to the MTP index.

Reboot works because a media scan is run as part of the boot sequence.